# Google Drive properties.insert Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Running the following code to create a property in Google drive API... been working for about 10 months then Friday it began to fail...

```
Service.Properties.Insert(New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Property() With    {.Visibility = "PUBLIC", .Key = "Category", .Value = fq.Category}, uploadedFile.Id).Execute()
```

I get the following error:

```
     Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Property not found: key = Category and visibility = PUBLIC [404]
Errors [
    Message[Property not found: key = Category and visibility = PUBLIC] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```

Anyone have any idea why this no longer works? I know that on Thursday they had an outage.

Comment: it's always useful to trace the http going over the wire, then use the Try It feature https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/insert#try-it to see narrow down the problem to an app problem or a Drive problem.

Comment: Same error over here. Worked for years, now stopped working.

Comment: Same error here as well.

Comment: It was an error with google code... they ended up fixing the issue but it too like 7 working days... crazy... Such a large company you would think that there would be like 99.9% up time. But lately it has been really bad...

Comment: Can this question be closed or flagged as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Since this was an error at Google side, and issue is solved this question shall be closed.